# about the type of raw pointer inside unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I read the book [The C++ Standard Library Second Edition] and found the section below:

```
namespace std {
template <typename T, typename D>
class unique_ptr<T[], D>
{
public:
typedef ... pointer; // may be D::pointer
typedef T element_type;
typedef D deleter_type;
...
};
}
```

The element type T might be void so that the unique pointer owns an object with an unspecified
type, like void* does. Note also that a type pointer is defined, which is not necessarily defined
as T*. If the deleter D has a pointer typedef, this type will be used instead. In such a case,
the template parameter T has only the effect of a type tag, because there is no member as part of
class unique_ptr<> that depends on T; everything depends on pointer. **The advantage is that a
unique_ptr can thus hold other smart pointers.**

I still cant not understand the purpose of "everything depends on pointer" after i reading this section.Is there anyone could provide some samples kindly?Thanks.

Comment: What don't you understand? Why the API is defined in terms of a typedef instead of `T*`? ... because it allows the API to be defined in terms of some other type, so is more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

[LWG issue 673](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#673) added `pointer` to the `unique_ptr` specification.  It contains this bullet point for motivation:

> - Efforts have been made to better support containers and smart pointers in shared memory contexts. One of the key hurdles in such
>     support is not assuming that a pointer type is actually a `T*`. This
>     can easily be accomplished for `unique_ptr` by having the deleter
>     define the pointer type: `D::pointer`. Furthermore this type can
>     easily be defaulted to `T*` should the deleter `D` choose not to
>     define a pointer type (example implementation here[broken link]). This
>     change has no run time overhead. It has no interface overhead on
>     authors of custom delter types. It simply allows (but not requires)
>     authors of custom deleter types to define a smart pointer for the
>     storage type of `unique_ptr` if they find such functionality useful.
>     `std::default_delete` is an example of a deleter which defaults
>     pointer to `T*` by simply ignoring this issue and not including a
>     `pointer typedef`.

See [`boost::offset_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.unique_ptr) for an example smart pointer that can reference shared memory.

Comment: Or, say that you had x86_64 code using the nice wide arithmetic operations and extra registers, but performing allocation from a process-wide 32-bit heap (because 4GB is plenty for the particular problem).  Then `std::unique_ptr`s might end up being only 4 bytes each, (after empty base class optimization eliminates the overhead for the deleter).  And this improves the effect of CPU cache.

Answer (score -1):

`unique_ptr` is designed in such a way that, if you don't provide a deleter in the declaration, thanks to default template parameters it uses a default_deleter(`std::default_delete<T>`) that just "`delete`" your pointer. It uses [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to look for the definition of "pointer" in your Deleter Type. If your `unique_ptr` holds another smart_ptr(which have the "pointer" defined), then in the destructor, it calls the deleter of the `unique_ptr` that you're holding.

Example:

```
class BufferClass
{
public:
    BufferClass()
    {
        // init
    }
    ~BufferClass()
    {
        delete [] buffer;
    }
    int *buffer;
};

// a short declaration for unique_ptr<BufferClass>
typedef unique_ptr<BufferClass> BufferPointer;    

BufferPointer myBuffer(new BufferClass(10)); // myBuffer holds BufferClass.
// when myBuffer goes out of scope, u'll have BufferClass::~BufferClass called.

//let's say you want to store a unique_ptr in another unique_ptr.     
unique_ptr<BufferPointer> myBufferPointerPointer(&myBuffer);
//  so when myBufferPointerPointer goes out of scope, BufferClass::~BufferClass will be called eventually
```